# How to create overlapping header in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar, sliverappbar

I'm kinda new to Flutter and I am trying to build a home page where the header is at the back of the main content. So when the app is scrolling, the content in front is overlapping the header.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocJIg.gif)

The main goal I want to achieve is overlapping scrolling. But it's nice if I can make the status bar color and the border radius changes when I scroll up the content, but I guess it's kinda advanced?

Can I user SliverAppBar to make it works like that? or are there any plugins for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  Draggable Scrollable Sheet for this with min height of 0.7 to 0.8.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html

Comment: Thankyou it works! But it has max height, so I can't scroll the content inside the Draggable Scrollable Sheet when it reached top of the screen.

Comment: user listview as child of scrollable sheet. it will work